Long Equation Exceeding Table Margins
I've encountered an issue where a long model specification equation exceeds the table margins. Below is the table I'm trying to create:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx} % Paquete para insertar unidades
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{microtype}  % new
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
%\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}

\end{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Detailed Model Specifications for Decomposed HHI Components}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Component} & \textbf{Geopolitical Event} & \textbf{Dependent Variable} & \textbf{Model Specification} \\
        \hline
        hhi\_iw\_div & Iraq War & ln(hhi\_iw\_div\(_{it}\)) & \multirow{15}{*}{\centering 
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth} 
        \begin{multline*} 
        = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \ln(\text{Patent Grants})_{it} + \beta_2 \text{Geopolitical Risk}_{it} + \beta_3 \text{Political Stability}_{it} + \beta_4 \text{Level of Democracy}_{it} \\
        + \beta_5 \text{Political Corruption}_{it} + \beta_6 \text{Political Imprisonment}_{it} + \beta_7 \text{The Quality of Government}_{it} + \beta_8 \ln(\text{Trade Openness})_{it} \\
        + \beta_9 \ln(\text{GDP per Capita})_{it} + \beta_{10} \ln(\text{Population Density})_{it} + \beta_{11} \ln(\text{Economic Freedom Index})_{it} \\
        + \beta_{12} \ln(\text{Tax Burden})_{it} + \epsilon_{it}
        \end{multline*}
        \end{minipage}} \\
        hhi\_iw\_risk & Iraq War & ln(hhi\_iw\_risk\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_iw\_cov & Iraq War & ln(hhi\_iw\_cov\(_{it}\)) & \\
        \cline{1-3}
        hhi\_as\_div & Arab Spring & ln(hhi\_as\_div\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_as\_risk & Arab Spring & ln(hhi\_as\_risk\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_as\_cov & Arab Spring & ln(hhi\_as\_cov\(_{it}\)) & \\
        \cline{1-3}
        hhi\_ac\_div & Annexation of Crimea & ln(hhi\_ac\_div\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_ac\_risk & Annexation of Crimea & ln(hhi\_ac\_risk\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_ac\_cov & Annexation of Crimea & ln(hhi\_ac\_cov\(_{it}\)) & \\
        \cline{1-3}
        hhi\_scw\_div & Syrian Civil War & ln(hhi\_scw\_div\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_scw\_risk & Syrian Civil War & ln(hhi\_scw\_risk\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_scw\_cov & Syrian Civil War & ln(hhi\_scw\_cov\(_{it}\)) & \\
        \cline{1-3}
        hhi\_opc\_div & 2014 Oil Price Collapse & ln(hhi\_opc\_div\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_opc\_risk & 2014 Oil Price Collapse & ln(hhi\_opc\_risk\(_{it}\)) & \\
        hhi\_opc\_cov & 2014 Oil Price Collapse & ln(hhi\_opc\_cov\(_{it}\)) & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}

output:


why 3 calls to fontenc 2 inputenc, 2 geometry 2 mathtools ?

You can gain a bit more width by making the column heading "Dependent Variable" two lines.  (That may not be enough though.)

Do you really need to insert the long formula in the table? It appears that it applies to everything in the table, so you can just typeset it below the table.

@egreg Thank you for the suggestion! I’m open to both options—either fitting the formula within the table or typesetting it below the table. My main goal is to ensure the presentation is clear and the tables look good for readers. If placing the formula outside the table enhances readability and presentation, I’m happy to go with that approach. Any tips on the best way to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

There's a lot of repetitive information in columns 1 and 3, and the expression you're trying to typeset in column 4 doesn't appear to be associated with any particular row in the first three columns. I therefore recommend that you simplify the table significantly, mainly by reducing it to just two columns. I would also give the (now much simplified) table a more open "look", by getting rid of all vertical rules and by starting to employ the user macros of the booktabs package. (A happy side effect of this simplification is that you won't need to typeset the table in landscape mode.) Finally, just provide a textual description of how the dependent variables are defined, along with a list of the 12 independent variables below the table.
Oh, and nothing good whatsoever ever comes from loading LaTeX packages repeatedly.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
%%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % oh no, not again
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % oh no, not again
%%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % oh no, not again
%%\usepackage{mathtools}      % oh no, not again
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
%%\usepackage[]{geometry}     % oh no, not again
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            %makecell, multirow, tabularx, % not needed here
            threeparttable}
%\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}  % not needed here
%\renewcommand\theadgape{}                 % not needed here
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
%%\usepackage{siunitx}        % oh no, not again
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{I trust you can come up with a suitable caption for this reduced-content table}
    \label{tab:HHI}
    
    \smallskip
    \begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{}}
        \toprule
        Geopolitical Event & Component variable \\
        \midrule
        Iraq War & hhi\_iw\_div   \\
                 & hhi\_iw\_risk  \\
                 & hhi\_iw\_cov   \\
        \addlinespace
        Arab Spring & hhi\_as\_div   \\
                    & hhi\_as\_risk  \\
                    & hhi\_as\_cov   \\
        \addlinespace
        Annexation of Crimea & hhi\_ac\_div   \\
                             & hhi\_ac\_risk  \\
                             & hhi\_ac\_cov   \\
        \addlinespace
        Syrian Civil War     & hhi\_scw\_div  \\
                             & hhi\_scw\_risk \\
                             & hhi\_scw\_cov  \\
        \addlinespace
        2014 Oil Price Collapse & hhi\_opc\_div  \\
                                & hhi\_opc\_risk \\
                                & hhi\_opc\_cov  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

In each of the 15 resulting regression models, the dependent variable is the natural logarithm of the corresponding component variable. Each dependent variable, in turn, is posited to depend linearly on a constant term and the following group of 12 independent variables: ln(Patent Grants), Geopolitical Risk, Political Stability, Level of Democracy, Political Corruption, Political Imprisonment, Quality of Government, ln(Trade Openness), ln(GDP per Capita), ln(Population Density), ln(Economic Freedom Index), and ln(Tax Burden).

\end{document}

